# Is it possible to use a non-Leonardo board to act as a keyboard or other device?

Tags: arduino, usb, surface-mount, usb-otg

I have been seeing lots of reports about the brand new Leonardo and it's capabilities, cheapness, and most popular, it's USB features. However, I look down at the ol' Arduino Uno and sigh. I don't mind not having the new features besides the USB reprogrammibility. I have read reports that there are ways to do this on the Uno, but they never said how. Someone else hinted that the ICSP headers for the USB port could reprogram the TX/RX to USB chip somehow. **So how do I do this if this is possible?**

**Edit:** Please don't have any posts that I have to solder anything to my board because I don't like modifying my boards; I don't know why, but I mostly don't like the unprofessional look of some SMD and some through hole parts and I don't want to resolder anything every time I want to do a different project, etc.

Comment: Learn to solder! It's a very useful skill, and you'll quickly hit a wall if you're genuinely interested in electronics and don't know how to solder.

Comment: @ConnorWolf That came out wrong. I *can* solder, I just don't like modifying Arduinos for some reason. I just meant I don't want to desolder this part and do this: I like it pretty much the way it is configured now. Plus, Arduino boards are too expensive to risk messing up and I have soldered very little: I like soldering cheaper components.

Comment: If you think an arduino is an expensive component, you're going to have trouble if you become serious about electronics. I've soldered on ICs that are more then a hundred dollars a piece (and that's pretty low for expensive components!), as well as assemblies that cost many thousands of dollars.

Comment: Besides, you can buy an arduino clone from china for ~$10-$15 dollars. That makes them a lot more disposable.

Comment: @ConnorWolf Why would I need to buy a $100 component? (Just wondering where you found *that* one) I know they aren't that pricey, but if I budgeted my Arduino buying and removed ~$20-25 from my funds, if I buy wisely from cheaper sources like eBay, I could easily buy 3 new detailed components for my collection. I also don't want to solder anything to the bottom, because it makes it wobbly if it is too big. Also, I like the clean look of only all through hole or only SMD parts; I hate michmached things. Also, it is too cold to solder and I don't like the idea of soldering inside my house.

Comment: 1: Some FPGAs are easily $100 + (they go into the many thousands of dollars for a single IC!).  Re: wobbly - You should be mounting the boards to something (like an enclosure) using standoffs anyways. Re: Soldering indoors - Why not? The fumes are harmless.

Comment: @ConnorWolf I've tried it once: I can smell though for a while. Re: Wobbly: I do when I'm done, but when developing, I don't like doing that yet and that is the time it is most annoying: when I am plugging in jumpers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep! Check out [this post by Michael Mitchell](http://mitchtech.net/arduino-usb-hid-keyboard/). All you need is a firmware update. Step-by-step instructions included.

Comment: So glad I don't need to solder anything because I have a SMD board... Great link!